# ¿Como saber en que rama estás en git sin consultarlo continuamente?

Tags: git, github, git-push, gitlab, git-commit

Buenas estoy siguiendo unos videostutoriales para aprender git y la persona que los está enseñando le sale la rama del proyecto en el que está por consola sin consultarlo continuamente, tal que así :

```
utillity-function[master]$
```

siendo **utillity-function** el >nombre del directorio y **master** el nombre de la rama, y a mi simplemente me aparece el nombre del directorio sin aparecer en la rama en la que estoy situado.

Comment: Eso es simplemente porque ha modificado la variable de entorno PS1 en su terminal para que aparezca la rama actual. Para consultar la rama a la que está apuntando tu HEAD, puedes escribir `git status`. Ten en cuenta que tener el nombre de la rama en como la tiene el del videotutorial puede conducir a confusión. Si por ejemplo estás en la rama master, y en otra consola cambias de rama, al volver a la primera consola te va a seguir apareciendo master, no se va a actualizar. La forma más segura de saber la rama actual es ejecutar `git status`.

Comment: Si aún así quieres modificar tu consola para que te salga de esa manera puedes probar cambiando tu variable de entorno PS1 como alguno de estos ejemplos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133904/ps1-line-with-git-current-branch-and-colors

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me ha ayudado mucho tu respuesta, es justo lo que buscaba

Comment: @AlvaroMenaParra  Si ya encontraste la respuesta a tu pregunta, escríbelo justamente como respuesta, detalladamente, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer). Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.